# How to put numerator and denominator in a canonical form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, canonicalization

I have the following expression that I obtained after some computation:

```
TDiscrete=-(R2/(R1 tauC^2 (R2/(R4 tauC^2) + (CC2 R2 (1 - y^2))/(
    CC1 R3 tauC^2 y) + (CC2^2 (1 - y^2)^2)/(CC1^2 tauC^2 y^2))))
```

I want Mathematica to display it in a canonical form, i.e. as a fraction of two polynomials dependent on y. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: `Simplify[TDiscrete]`?

Answer (score 2):

You may do the following. This is your expression:

```
TDiscrete = -(R2/(R1 tauC^2 (R2/(R4 tauC^2) + (CC2 R2 (1 - 
             y^2))/(CC1 R3 tauC^2 y) + (CC2^2 (1 - y^2)^2)/(CC1^2 tauC^2 y^2))));
```

Let us first simplify it:

```
expr1 = Simplify[TDiscrete]
```

and look at it:

```
expr1//TraditionalForm
```

[image]

If that is what you are after, that's it.

However we can do more.

Let us define the Tree Coordinate of the subexpression `CC1^2 R2 R3 y^2 - CC1 CC2 R2 R4 y (-1 + y^2) + CC2^2 R3 R4 (-1 + y^2)^2` entering the previous result:

```
Position[expr1,CC1^2 R2 R3 y^2 - CC1 CC2 R2 R4 y (-1 + y^2) + CC2^2 R3 R4 (-1 + y^2)^2]

(*  {{8, 1}}   *)
```

and expand this term:

```
expr2 = MapAt[Expand, expr1, {8, 1}]

(*  -((CC1^2 R2 R3 R4 y^2)/(R1 (CC2^2 R3 R4 + CC1 CC2 R2 R4 y + 
       CC1^2 R2 R3 y^2 - 2 CC2^2 R3 R4 y^2 - CC1 CC2 R2 R4 y^3 + 
       CC2^2 R3 R4 y^4)))  *)


expr2//TraditionalForm/.a_/b_:>a/b
```

[image]

In this expanded subexpression one can collect the terns with the same powers and then sort  the terms in the assending order.

```
 f[x_] := Last[x][[2]]
expr3 = MapAt[
  HoldForm[Evaluate[SortBy[Collect[#, Table[y^n, {n, 4}]], 1/f]]] &, 
  expr2, {8, 1}]

expr3 // TraditionalForm /. a_/b_ :> a/b
```

[image]

Do not forget, that I used `HoldForm` to keep the order of the terms unchanged by MMa. Therefore, if you need to further use the result, apply first `ReleaseHold`to it.

Have fun!

Comment: Get is easier  `TDiscrete // Together `

Comment: @Akku14 which yields a bit different result.